# angular + nodejs console shows "GET http://localhost:4200/user/profile 401 (Unauthorized) "

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I'm trying to store data into /profile after logging in. However, I keep getting these 2 errors in the console after logging in.

> "VM276:1 GET http://localhost:4200/user/profile 401 (Unauthorized)"
> and "HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized"".

Since i'm following different tutorials to work this out so I know that I've made some mistake with the token code, I just don't know how to fix it. And I would like to thank anyone who's spending time to help! This is my authentication.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';


export interface UserDetails{
  username: string
  email: string
  password: string
  exp: number
  iat: number
}
interface TokenResponse{
  token: string
}
export interface TokenPayload{
  username: string
  email: string
  password: string
}
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  private token: string

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  private saveToken(token: string): void{
    localStorage.setItem('usertoken', token)
    this.token = token
  }
  private getToken(): string{
    if(!this.token){
      this.token = localStorage.getItem('usertoken')
    }
    return this.token
  }
  public getUserDetails(): UserDetails{
    const token = this.getToken()
    let payload
    if(token){
      payload = token.split('.')[1]
      payload = window.atob(payload)
      return JSON.parse(payload)
    }else{
      return null
    }
  }
  public isLoggedIn(): boolean{
    const user = this.getUserDetails()
    if(user){
      return user.exp > Date.now()/ 1000
    }
    else{
      return false
    }
  }
  public login(user: TokenPayload): Observable<any>{
    const base = this.http.post('/user/login', user)
    const request = base.pipe(
      map((data: TokenResponse) => {
        if(data.token){
          this.saveToken(data.token)
        }return data
      })
    )
    return request
  }
  public register(user: TokenPayload) : Observable<any>{
    const base = this.http.post('/user/register', user)
    const request = base.pipe(
      map((data: TokenResponse) => {
        if(data.token){
          this.saveToken(data.token)
        }
        return data
      })
    )
    return request
  }
  public profile(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('/user/profile',{
      headers: {Authorization: `${this.getToken()}`}
    })
  }
  public logout(): void{
    this.token = ''
    window.localStorage.removeItem('usertoken')
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/')
  }

}
```

This is my profile.component.ts

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  details: UserDetails

  constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.profile().subscribe(
      user => {
        this.details = user
      },
      err => {
        console.error(err)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

this is my auth.js

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.header("token");
  if (!token) return res.status(401).json({ message: "Auth Error" });

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "randomString");
    req.user = decoded.user;
    next();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.status(500).send({ message: "Invalid Token" });
  }
};
```

and this is my /routes/user.js

```
// Filename : user.js

const express = require("express");
const {check, validationResult} = require("express-validator");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const router = express.Router();
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");
const User = require("../model/User");



/**
 * @method - POST
 * @param - /signup
 * @description - User SignUp
 */

router.post(
    "/register",
    [
        check("username", "Please Enter a Valid Username")
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
        check("email", "Please enter a valid email").isEmail(),
        check("password", "Please enter a valid password").isLength({
            min: 6
        })
    ],
    async (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                errors: errors.array()
            });
        }

        const {
            username,
            email,
            password
        } = req.body;
        try {
            let user = await User.findOne({
                email
            });
            if (user) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    msg: "User Already Exists"
                });
            }

            user = new User({
                username,
                email,
                password
            });

            const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
            user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

            await user.save();

            const payload = {
                user: {
                    id: user.id
                }
            };

            jwt.sign(
                payload,
                "randomString", {
                    expiresIn: 10000
                },
                (err, token) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    res.status(200).json({
                        token
                    });
                }
            );
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            res.status(500).send("Error in Saving");
        }
    }
);
router.post(
    "/login",
    [
      check("email", "Please enter a valid email").isEmail(),
      check("password", "Please enter a valid password").isLength({
        min: 6
      })
    ],
    async (req, res) => {
      const errors = validationResult(req);
  
      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          errors: errors.array()
        });
      }
  
      const { email, password } = req.body;
      try {
        let user = await User.findOne({
          email
        });
        if (!user)
          return res.status(400).json({
            message: "User Does Not Exist"
          });
  
        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (!isMatch)
          return res.status(400).json({
            message: "Incorrect Password!"
          });
  
        const payload = {
          user: {
            id: user.id
          }
        };
  
        jwt.sign(
          payload,
          "randomString",
          {
            expiresIn: 3600
          },
          (err, token) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.status(200).json({
              token
            });
          }
        );
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        res.status(500).json({
          message: "Server Error"
        });
      }
    }
  );

  /**
 * @method - POST
 * @description - Get LoggedIn User
 * @param - /user/me
 */

router.get("/profile", auth, async (req, res) => {

    try {
      // request.user is getting fetched from Middleware after token authentication
      const user = await User.findById(req.user.id);
      res.json(user);
    } catch (e) {
      res.send({ message: "Error in Fetching user" });
    }
  });
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your angular app you are sending the token with the `authorization` header

```
Authorization: token
```

But in your API (`auth.js`), you are trying to access the `token` header

```
req.header("token")
```

Replace you api code with

```
req.header("authorization")
```